# Why doesn't my Dell XPS wifi (iwlwifi) work with kernel 4.15.0-64?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, kernel, dell, iwlwifi

My WiFi stopped working 9/23/19, and trying to figure out what changed, it looks like it works with kernel version 4.15.0-60-generic, but fails with newer kernel 4.15.0-64. Any idea why or what to do?

Details of my setup:

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.3

machine: [Dell XPS 15 7590](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/xps-15-7590-laptop/docs)

network driver: iwlwifi

lspci with the working kernel:

```
$ lspci -nnk |grep Network -A3
3b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
  Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Device [1a56:1654]
  Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
  Kernel modules: iwlwifi

sudo lshw -C network
*-network
  description: Ethernet interface
  product: Intel Corporation
  vendor: Intel Corporation
  physical id: 0
  bus info: pci@0000:3b:00.0
  logical name: wlp59s0
  version: 1a
  serial: <removed>
  width: 64 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
  configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-60-generic firmware=48.4fa0041f.0 ip=10.12.33.131 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes
  resources: irq:16 memory:ed400000-ed403fff
```

[Edit:] 
lspci with the broken kernel:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Network controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:3b:00.0
   version: 1a
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:ed400000-ed403fff
```

rfkill output:
when it works (old kernel):

```
$ sudo rfkill list
    0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

When it doesn't work (new kernels):

```
$  sudo rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: This may be a bug. I suggest to install hwe kernel.

Comment: Please [edit] yout question and add output of `rfkill list`.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a kernel bug. The easiest way is to upgrade to a HWE kernel.

Run in a terminal

```
sudo apt install linix-generic-hwe-18.04
```

and reboot.

Comment: I tried that, and got kernel 5.0.0-29, and it did NOT work :(

Comment: Did you install any wifi drivers? It means that this is not the kernel problem.

Comment: not sure how exactly you need to install drivers. As far as I know, it should still use the same driver. I DO see iwlwifi in the 4.15.0-64-generic directory. I tried to 'modprobe' it, but nothing seemed to change. Seems like iwlwifi stopped claiming up this adapter?